# How to get maximum employee in a company by their HireDate and TerminationDate?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new at this. So I need a help for my PostgreSQL query. I have a table named Employee which is like:

```
ID | FirstName | LastName | HireDate   | TerminationDate | Salary
---+-----------+----------+------------+-----------------+-------
1  | Peter     | Jones    | 2010-06-20 | 2016-01-01      | 1000
2  | Eva       | Johnson  | 2010-02-12 | NULL            | 2000
3  | Ryan      | Kent     | 2012-03-14 | 2014-01-01      | 2000
4  | Jack      | River    | 2013-09-10 | NULL            | 3000
5  | Thomas    | Lex      | 2013-09-10 | NULL            | 2000
6  | Gerald    | Smith    | 2015-04-10 | 2015-05-01      | 4000
```

How do I get all of the information of the employee where I have to add another column showing the maximum number of employees hired by the company during their period of service, and the date where that maximum number of employees acquired?

Where the table should look like this

```
ID | FirstName | LastName | HireDate   | TerminationDate | Salary | MaxEmp | DateAcq
---+-----------+----------+------------+-----------------+--------+--------+-----------
1  | Peter     | Jones    | 2010-06-20 | 2016-01-01      | 1000   | 5      | 2015-04-10
2  | Eva       | Johnson  | 2010-02-12 | NULL            | 2000   | 5      | 2015-04-10
3  | Ryan      | Kent     | 2012-03-14 | 2014-01-01      | 2000   | 5      | 2013-09-10
4  | Jack      | River    | 2013-09-10 | NULL            | 3000   | 5      | 2015-04-10
5  | Thomas    | Lex      | 2013-09-10 | NULL            | 2000   | 5      | 2015-04-10
6  | Gerald    | Smith    | 2015-04-10 | 2015-05-01      | 4000   | 5      | 2015-04-10
```

Where MaxEmp is the max number of employees hired by the company during his/her period of service, DateAcq is the date where the max number acquired, and the NULL records in TerminationDate shows that the employee still work on the company.

Comment: What database engine are you using? Cannot be all 3. SQL server? Mysql? Postgres? Also post the query you have tried to use to get the expected result.

Comment: I'm using postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query shows changes of employment over time:

```
select sum(count) over (order by dateaq) as maxemp, dateaq
from (
    select hiredate as dateaq, 1 as count
    from employee
    union all
    select terminationdate, -1
    from employee
    where terminationdate is not null
    ) s;

 maxemp |   dateaq   
--------+------------
      1 | 2010-02-12
      2 | 2010-06-20
      3 | 2012-03-14
      5 | 2013-09-10
      5 | 2013-09-10
      4 | 2014-01-01
      5 | 2015-04-10
      4 | 2015-05-01
      3 | 2016-01-01
(9 rows)
```

As you can see, the maximum employment was 5 people, because Ryan and Gerald were not employed at the same time.

Join these results with the table and select maximum values for each employee:

```
select distinct on (id) *
from employee e
join (
    select sum(count) over (order by dateaq) as maxemp, dateaq
    from (
        select hiredate as dateaq, 1 as count
        from employee
        union all
        select terminationdate, -1
        from employee
        where terminationdate is not null
        ) s
    ) s on dateaq between hiredate and coalesce(terminationdate, 'infinity')
order by id, maxemp desc, dateaq desc;

 id | firstname | lastname |  hiredate  | terminationdate | salary | maxemp |   dateaq   
----+-----------+----------+------------+-----------------+--------+--------+------------
  1 | Peter     | Jones    | 2010-06-20 | 2016-01-01      |   1000 |      5 | 2015-04-10
  2 | Eva       | Johnson  | 2010-02-12 |                 |   2000 |      5 | 2015-04-10
  3 | Ryan      | Kent     | 2012-03-14 | 2014-01-01      |   2000 |      5 | 2013-09-10
  4 | Jack      | River    | 2013-09-10 |                 |   3000 |      5 | 2015-04-10
  5 | Thomas    | Lex      | 2013-09-10 |                 |   2000 |      5 | 2015-04-10
  6 | Gerald    | Smith    | 2015-04-10 | 2015-05-01      |   4000 |      5 | 2015-04-10
(6 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried it on my query and it worked. I learned a lot from your code. And thank you also for the correction. I checked it and yes, I was wrong.